# Base64 encoding in Sproutcore

Tags: javascript, base64, sproutcore, sproutcore-views

I need to invoke restful webservices in Sproutcore which requires authentication header for http request. I write a code like in Sproutcore:

```
authHeader: function () {
    var userAndPass = "username:password";
    var auth = "Basic " + Base64.encode(userAndPass);
    return auth;
},
```

However, when I run it, sadi Base64 is not defined.

Anybody knows how to fix it or do it in sproutcore. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`btoa()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.atob) for Base-64 encodeing.

```
var auth = "Basic " + btoa(userAndPass);
```

Comment: It works on all browsers, except IE... But!... you can use this http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-base64.html